# Uploadify v3 onUploadError howto

Tags: uploadify

Been playing around with `Uploadify v3` for few days now and just came to realize some of the codes have been rewritten, for example, `onError` is no longer existed, I am assuming it's been replaced by `onUploadError`.

What i am trying to achieve is to be able to return non-compliance error to users either through putting a message in the div (preferred method) or alert.
Looking at the closest solution [How to trigger uploadify onError event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036296/how-to-trigger-uploadify-onerror-event-handler), but it's outdated as it's for v2.

Using the same method as the outdated post up there, I have `$("#fileInput").uploadify()` with onUploadError added:

```
'onUploadError' : function(file,errorCode,errorMsg) {
        var r = '<br />ERROR: ';
        switch(errorMsg) {
                case 405:
                        r += 'Invalid file type.';
                        break;
                case 406:
                        r += 'Some other error.';
                        break;
        }
        alert(r);
        setTimeout('$("#fileInput'+ ID + 'span.data").html("'+r+'");',111);                      
}
```

The problems I am having right now are:

1. Alert returns undefined using the codes above
2. setTimeout doesn't do anything

How can you solve these problems?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a little too late... but anyway I try to answer.

I'm also playing around with v3 of uploadify. onError() does no longer exists, it has been replaced by onUploadError(). The erroror object given by the old onError event does no longer exists. Now to check for the type of error you can switch on the errorCode argument (the second given in the callback), which is numeric. I've not found a table with all possible error codes, but doing some trials I discovered the following three error codes:

-200: HTTP errors (e.g. HTTP 500, 400, 404, etc.)
-220: IO errors (e.g. connection closed without response from the server, or errors while rading the source file from the user's PC)
-280: don't have actually fully understood what kind of errors they are, but is seems to be errors gracefully handled by uploadify. For example, if you try to add to the queue a file that is already in the queue, uploadify ask you whether you want to replace the file that's currently enqueued, or cancel the operation. If you cancel, an error is fired with code -280.

To check for the specific type of error, for example to get the specific HTTP error code (in case the error is an http error), you can check the error message, which is the third argument. This argument is a string, not a number, so you cannot use a switch .. case as in your example (or at least it's not that simple to use a switch .. case with strings). Simply use an if .. else if .. else.

Hope this can help...

I'm still looking for a complete list of the possible error codes given in the errorCode argument of the event handler. If someone knows, please tell me!

Comment: Ok, finally I've found an answer directly inside the source code of SWFUpload 2.2, on which uploadify is based.

The error code -280 is simply "Upload cancelled", nothing more than this :)

The full list of possible upload errors is the following:
HTTP_ERROR   : -200,
MISSING_UPLOAD_URL  : -210,
IO_ERROR   : -220,
SECURITY_ERROR   : -230,
UPLOAD_LIMIT_EXCEEDED  : -240,
UPLOAD_FAILED   : -250,
SPECIFIED_FILE_ID_NOT_FOUND : -260,
FILE_VALIDATION_FAILED  : -270,
FILE_CANCELLED   : -280,
UPLOAD_STOPPED   : -290